# Iphone MPMoviePlayer Notification

Tags: iphone, notifications, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using a MpMoviePlayerController To play video in my aap. I want to handle the notification sent by tapping the control button displayed in the red circle in below image.

[alt text http://grab.by/5iOY](http://grab.by/5iOY)

Can any one help me out which notification does this control button fires???

**UPdates:**
I tried it in this way,

```
NSString * filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
self.player = [[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url] autorelease];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieDidExitFullScreen:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification
                                           object:self.player.moviePlayer];
[self.window addSubview:self.player.view];
```

And the function in selector is:

```
-(void)movieDidExitFullScreen:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"Movie player did exit full screen");}
```

But the function never gets called when tapping the control button.

Please let me know if m doing some thing wrong.

Regards,

Nic

Answer (score 1):

your selector function should be like this

```
-(void)movieDidExitFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will generate the [`MPMoviePlayerScalingModeDidChangeNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW104). When you receive the notification, you should check the value of the [`scalingMode`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW11) property to determine which scaling mode the player was switched to.

**Update**:

Looking at the documentation for the `MPMoviePlayerController` (more specifically, the [`MPMovieControlStyle`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MPMovieControlStyle) enumeration), the button you want to handle seems to be the switch between embedded and full-screen view. This one should generate [`MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW53) (and the corresponding `WillExit` and `DidEnter`/`DidExit` notifications).

Comment: Hi Franci thanks for your reply. I checked it but this control button does not send that notification. "MPMoviePlayerScalingModeDidChangeNotification" notification is sent by the control button at the end of the progress indicator.